# Books that discuss practical rendering techniques?

Tags: rendering, books, binary-space-partitioning, quake3

I'm looking for some books that discuss practical rendering topics like say rendering a bsp level or md2/3 mode, making a little quake like game as the goal or something to that effect. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any rendering then you should develop an understanding of the foundation frameworks that will be used, as well as an understanding of the rendering pipeline as a whole. OpenGL and DirectX are the two primary standards for rendering graphics, with OpenGL having many varieties depending on the target platform, and DirectX being microsoft exclusive.

Something like this is a good start for DirectX
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-3D-Game-Programming-DirectX/dp/1936420228/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1360540306&sr=8-1&keywords=directx](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936420228)

And this is one of the standard books for OpenGL
[http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-SuperBible-Comprehensive-Tutorial-Reference/dp/0321712617/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1360540469&sr=8-2&keywords=opengl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321712617)

Comment: i have decent knowledge of using OpenGL , what i lack is practical stuff like implementing bsp trees and some common file formats

Comment: Okay, well here are a couple links for binary space partitioning theory, as well as the wikipedia for the BSP file format, which contains additional links at the bottom describing each of the major BSP file format iterations in detail. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSP_(file_format), http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/bsp/document.html

Comment: but no blooks that would discuss everything in one place?

Comment: Questions that just ask for lists are considered non-constructive for SE sites.  There are a lot of such books, but asking on a forum like gamedev.net is more appropriate.